# Computing the parameter statement within the subroutine

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Say I have a subroutine:

```
subroutine calledalot()
   real, parameter :: dir1=1./3., dir2=2./3., dir3=3./3.

   random_number=random_function(seed)
   if ( random_number <= dir1 ) then
      command1
   else if ( random_number <= dir2 ) then
      command2
   else if ( random_number <= dir3 ) then
      command3
   end if
end
```

Will the division in the variable declaration statement be computed every time the subroutine is called?

Comment: No: parameters are computed at compile time.

Comment: you do realize being integers the values will be 0,0,1 ...

Comment: My bad! I do see that. Fixed it.